# Linhas em Colunas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um select de uma tabela usando o CTE no SQL Server, e estou em dúvida para transformar as linhas do resultados em colunas.

São 5 colunas fixas, não tem a necessidade de ser dinâmica.

```
WITH conta_pai AS (
SELECT
    m.CODIGO,
    m.nome,
    m.CONTAS_BALANCETE_CONTA_PAI
FROM CONTAS_BALANCETE m
WHERE m.codigo = 145

UNION ALL

SELECT
  m.codigo,
  m.NOME,
  m.CONTAS_BALANCETE_CONTA_PAI
FROM conta_pai
JOIN CONTAS_BALANCETE m ON m.CODIGO = conta_pai.CONTAS_BALANCETE_CONTA_PAI
)

SELECT conta_pai.nome
FROM conta_pai
```

Esse é o resultado que tenho:

```
nome
---------------------
VALE TRANSPORTE
ENCARGOS
DESPESAS COM PESSOAL
DESPESAS OPERACIONAIS
DESPESAS
```

Necessito desse resultado:

```
coluna1            coluna2    coluna3                coluna4                 coluna5
-----------------|----------|----------------------|-----------------------|---------
VALE TRANSPORTE  | ENCARGOS | DESPESAS COM PESSOAL | DESPESAS OPERACIONAIS | DESPESAS
```

Já tentei usar o PIVOT ou Concatenar e não consegui.

Qual seria a melhor forma de gerar esse script para trazer o resultado da forma desejada?

Comment: Utiliza o OUTER APPLY que irás conseguir!

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma sugestão para testes onde foi adicionada uma coluna na CTE para numerar as linhas para converte-las posteriormente em colunas com o Pivot:

```
WITH conta_pai AS 
(
  SELECT
    m.CODIGO,
    m.nome,
    m.CONTAS_BALANCETE_CONTA_PAI,
    1 as COLUNA
  FROM CONTAS_BALANCETE m
  WHERE m.codigo = 145

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    m.codigo,
    m.NOME,
    m.CONTAS_BALANCETE_CONTA_PAI,
    conta_pai.COLUNA + 1
  FROM conta_pai
  JOIN CONTAS_BALANCETE m ON m.CODIGO = conta_pai.CONTAS_BALANCETE_CONTA_PAI
)

SELECT 
    [1] as COLUNA1,
    [2] as COLUNA2,
    [3] as COLUNA3,
    [4] as COLUNA4,
    [5] as COLUNA5
FROM conta_pai
PIVOT
(
    MAX(nome) FOR COLUNA IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) as p
```